# Adding RFID Plugin from Wiki ros

Tags: plugins, ros

I am having difficulty understanding how the plugin is added to the robot model that i have and also to spawn it in the gazebo world.

[http://wiki.ros.org/RFIDsensor_Gazebo_plugin#:~:text=The%20plugin%20is%20a%20ros,back%20from%20the%20activated%20tags](http://wiki.ros.org/RFIDsensor_Gazebo_plugin#:%7E:text=The%20plugin%20is%20a%20ros,back%20from%20the%20activated%20tags).

The above link directs you to the plugin page.
I know that this question is going be very long and silly but I would like someone to go through it with me.

I added the plugins as said in the website to my ".xacro" file.

1. The rfid tag plugin has a reference name "base_link". What does this mean and how it helps to spawn the Tags in the world.
2. The rfid antenna plugin in the website has first a link made for the antenna which i later made a joint with the robot to position it. Then below it is the plugin with reference name as = "base_link". Why would the reference name be "base_link". Shouldn't it be the name of the antenna link?
3. TF launch in the website, I am unaware of what the args are doing and where is it mapping the tags too?

Thank you

I am expecting to launch a rfid antenna and tags from the plugin to the simulation gazebo world